# Counting how many times a digit occurs in each string in a column not working properly

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

While trying to count the digits contained in a DataFrame column, I discovered that the first line below doesn't work properly (returns always 0) while the second yes and I was wondering why the first one doesn't operate correctly.

```
# The line below returns  always 0 'text_field_w_digits'(incorrect)  
df['count_digits'] = df['text_field_w_digits'].map(lambda x: x.count(r'\d'))

# The line below correctly returns the number of digits contained in  'text_field_w_digits'  
df['count_digits'] = df['text_field_w_digits'].str.count(r'\d') # returns correct
```

Thank you in advance for helping a newbie!

Comment: Former is usual python string method, that doesn't recognize regex.

Comment: Former is possible via `df['text_field_w_digits'].apply(lambda x: len([s for s in x if s.isdigit()]))`

Comment: @JohnGalt thank you for your prompt replies. So the count in the first line is a different method from the second one?

Comment: Yes. Former is python string method, later is pandas series string method.